# How can I make battles in war interesting?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

My party is leading an army into war and I was wondering how I could make the battles interesting and enjoyable. Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Could you clarify whether you're asking as a player or a DM? Any other details you can provide - the scale of the battle, character levels, what role you expect them to play in the fights (i.e. supporting role or primary actor), etc. - would also be helpful in answering your question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to RPG.se! So, one thing to note is that we are not a traditional forum. If you take our [tour] you can quickly see some of the ways we are different. One of them is that we don't do idea generation questions. However, if you had a specific problem you were trying to overcome and [edit]ed that into your question I think this could be one we can handle. Otherwise, this question will likely be put on hold.

Comment: If you are confused by anything on the site please do take that [tour] and check the [help] or you can ping one of us in chat by putting "@[username] [message]" into a comment here and we'd be happy to help out if we can.